# DTEXEC imported text file location

Tags: ssis, bulkinsert, dtexec

Does anybody know where the intermediate text file is stored by DTEXEC when it uses BULK INSERT for fast import the localy stored Excel file?

As far as I know the BULK INSERT command can import only a text file, moreover, this text file must be placed in the location accessible for the SQL server.

How DTEXEC deals with this issue?

Thanks a lot!
Tomek

Comment: Are you sure BULK INSERT is used in that scenario? What's the situation you are dealing with, are you executing a SSIS package, running SQL Server "Import Export" wizard or something else?

Comment: As I wrote, I Use DTEXEC.exe. It uniqly determines I use dtsx package running locally. 
Depending on the task, the source file is either excel workbook or text CSV file.

In dtsx I have the option AccessMode set to 3 (OpenRowset Using FastLoad) what determines FAST LOAD. As I red in available web documents, it denotes BULK INSERT. Moreover the other options that can be set corresponds to BULK INSERT parameters.

My important question is about a way the text file (as Excel is always converted to txt by DTEXEC) is uploaded to the location accessible by SQL Server.

Comment: Ok, so you're using dtsx package (also known as SSIS package) to import data. I'm quite sure SSIS doesn't convert excel to txt automatically in any case. It doesn't matter that you set the destination as FAST LOAD, it only applies in cases where it's possible. You're right what you said about that setting, but I believe it's irrelevant in this case. More information about importing Excel files to SQL Server here (including SSIS): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15